# How to configure Terminal to be "Putty-like" when it comes to copy-paste with mouse?

Tags: terminal

As a long time Putty user, I love how upon selecting a text it gets copied  into the buffer and upon right clicking it gets pasted back in.

Is there a way to configure Terminal to behave the same way?

Comment: I like that feature, too - but ⌘-C ⌘-V is pretty quick :)

Comment: Use **iTerm2** as described [here](https://superuser.com/a/1677731/1071768)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Terminal is limited in its configurability but [iTerm2](http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/) is a Terminal replacement that does what you ask and more. Including bookmarks for ssh sessions not unlike puTTY.

Comment: Looks interesting. How to you set cut and paste up as i described though? I don't see this under Preferences

Comment: Preferences windows -> General tab. Make sure `Copy to clipboard on selection` is checked under the **Mouse** section.

Comment: iTerm is the best. +1

Comment: @Ian That will copy to the clipboard when text is hilighted, but won't paste on a right click.  It brings up the context menu.  It doesn't look like there is an option to do this, but it seems useful.

Comment: @KeithB: What's a "right click"? :) But seriously, there's an option to make the middle button paste from clipboard. It's just down from the copy-on-select option.

Comment: I use a macbook and a magic trackpad on my desktop.  No middle button, no right button.  I do have my trackpad setup to do a right click when I tap with two fingers.  I don't know of any way to easily do a middle click on a track pad.  However, I sent the iTerm developer some email, and this was added to the desired feature list.  Hopefully it will get added sometime soon.

Comment: Install BetterTouchTool and you can map more gestures than OS X lets you map by default. I have four finger tap mapped to middle click.

Comment: 2 KeithB: in iTerm2 go to "Options -> General -> install test-release updates (or something like this)", check for updates, install last test-release (1.0.0.20130622 by now) and get new option "Right button single click -> Paste from Selection" in Options -> General -> Pointer. I spend half an hour after migrating to new Mac finding this :) Good luck!

Answer (score 10):

If you have a three-button mouse (e.g., the Apple Mighty Mouse scroll ball can act as a third button), Terminal will paste the current selection if you **Middle-Click** (just like X11 and xterm). It is the same as invoking the **Edit > Paste Selection** command, which has the keyboard shortcut **Shift-Command-V**.

As of OS X 10.8, selecting text in a terminal copies the text to a pasteboard and **Paste Selection** pastes the contents of this pasteboard (akin to X11’s PRIMARY). It now behaves very much like xterm under X11. As a result, **Paste Selection** and **Middle-Click** are now available when there is no selection, pasting the same text until something else is selected, and the text persists when quitting/reopening Terminal. The pasteboard has the identifier `com.apple.Terminal.selection` and is available to other programs.

Also, you can drag-and-drop selected text to Paste it. You can of course drag to other terminal windows (or other applications), but you can also just drag a few pixels and then release to Paste into the current terminal.

Comment: Shift+Cmd+V still works on Ventura.

Answer (score 10):

NO need to download anything. In Terminal do

1. select text to copy
2. to paste, click the middle button of the mouse, or
   (cmd + shift + v)

I just tried in Yosemite.

Also works in High Sierra.

Comment: Whatttt how did I just discover this?! Works on mtn lion too

Comment: Yes, as I said in my answer four years earlier: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/21544/6883

Answer (score 4):

shift-⌘-V works on El Capitan. Feel free to edit if you have information about earlier releases

Comment: It works but it does not copy the selected contents to the Clipboard.

Comment: Yes, as I said in my answer five years earlier: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/21544/6883

Answer (score 2):

Highlight the command and press <kbd>Shift-Cmd-V</kbd> to paste the highlighted data.

Comment: Yes, as I said in my answer eight years earlier: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/21544/6883

Answer (score 0):

Simply install http://totalterminal.binaryage.com/ which includes both these options in the preferences.